# react + keycloak + rerender forces new authentification

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

I am using react with keycloak-js and the framework react-keycloak from panz3r ([Link to library](https://github.com/panz3r/react-keycloak#readme) ) Everything latest version.

I have almost the same structure like this example here: [My project](https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak-examples/tree/master/examples/react-router)
I am using Functional Components and my App.tsx is also used as container -> I have all states defined here, which will be needed over all components.

Therefore my app looks like this (modified it for simplicity):
import packages

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
    const keycloakConfig = new (Keycloak as any)({
        realm: 'master',
        url: http://localhost:8280/auth/",
        clientId: 'reactPage',
    });

    const keycloakProviderInitConfig = {
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
    }


    const [data1, setData1] = useState<(Data[])>([]);
    const [data2, setData2] = useState<(Data | null)>(null);
    const [data3, setData3] = useState<(Data[])>([]);


    function onKeycloakEvent(event: any, error: any) {
        console.log('onKeycloakEvent', event, error)
        if (event === "onAuthSuccess") {
          setData1(Set anything);
        }
    }

    function onKeycloakTokens(tokens: any) {
        console.log('onKeycloakTokens', tokens)
    }

    return (
        <KeycloakProvider
            keycloak={keycloakConfig}
            initConfig={keycloakProviderInitConfig}
            onEvent={onKeycloakEvent}
            onTokens={onKeycloakTokens}
        >
            <Router history={myhistory}>
                <div className="App">
                    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                        <React.StrictMode>
                            <RouterComponent
                                data1={data1}
                             data2={data2}
                             ...
                        </React.StrictMode>
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                </div>
            </Router>
        </KeycloakProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

The problem:
As soon as I modify any data in the app.tsx container react rerenders the page and the authentification starts again from the beginning.
Now I have an endless loop. It does not matter from where I set any data in the container (app.tsx) as soon as I modify any variable in the container I have a complete rerender of the app and also a new authentification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix my problem with adding an extra layer before App.tsx. Maybe not the best solution, but it works